# Upgrade PHP 5.1.6 to 5.2.x on Fedora 6 - Solutions?

Tags: php, fedora

I have a CRM on an old Fedora server, running Apache 2.2.6, MySQL 5.0.27, and PHP 5.1.6.  I see a couple of options to fix my problem, but I thought I would consult the pros on this one here at Server Fault to see if I'm missing anything.  This is after spending a good while searching the net for solutions.

**Option 1**

Upgrade Fedora, step-wise, to Fedora 7 and then to 8, and then the PHP packages I need would be available.  I know this is hazardous, because of repository location, dependencies, etc.

**Option 2**

Upgrade using [this method](http://www.zygmund.net/blog/?p=17).  This may or may not work, and so would be considered a crap shoot.

I consulted some IT people and they say the best best is to back up data and build a new server with updated hard and software.  I happen to agree, but wanted to exhaust all my resources first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy a new server, reinstall LAMP and then start from scratch.  Use something like Ubuntu 9.1o or 10.04, which are both very stable.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do is sidegrade Fedora 6 to CentOS 5 so that you stop losing ground. After that, there are several well-tested paths to upgrade to 5.2.

Comment: Yah, good point.  This could be accomplished with Ubuntu 9.10 as well.

Comment: Except that Ubuntu will require a complete reinstall. A sidegrade from Fedora to CentOS is not a supported procedure, but can be done.